# List of limitations, what iPhone Apps cannot do with iPhone resources

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, app-store

I am not getting any proper documentation, in which **"things that cannot be done"** in iPhone App are listed. For example access to Audio Recorder, Message App, Mail App, Video Player,etc.

Any useful link for that?

Comment: refer this : - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: I assume you mean things that cannot be done according to the iOS Developer standard agreement, the App store guidelines, and using only the published public iOS SDK APIs?

Comment: @hotpaw2: Yes, Exactly. Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The published public APIs say what is possible.  The opposite, what might be impossible using only these APIs, is probably an infinite set.

There is also a reported variance in whether apps containing specific implementations of a particular feature are approved or not when submitted for review.  Thus the only final document for certain things might be individual app approvals and rejections.  Apple legal may or may not allow or want to clarify any perceived rule ambiguity.

Apple also revises the Developer agreement and guidelines from time to time, such that apps that currently weren't possible become allowed (certain exposed interpreters and emulators, for instance), and vice-versa.

So the best lists might be the summaries and growing lists of reports of all the different rejections various developers have encountered.

Answer (score 0):

A general introduction can be found in [Apple's public documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ApplicationDevelopmentOverview/DeliverYourAppontheAppStore/DeliverYourAppontheAppStore.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011186-CH8-SW1).

You can also read the [AppStore Review Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) to get more detailed information. But this requires a login.

You can only interact with other apps via urls. See [Apple URL Scheme Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007891-SW1).

For some other tasks such as sending mails and messages, you can use the [`MessageUI` Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/_index.html).

Comment: Nice Documents, but cannot find anything related to limitation to access iPhone resources.

Comment: The apps you listed can (if at all) only be accessed through documented URL-schemes. The "things that cannot be done" in an iPhone App are listed in the documents above. I will try to find the url-schema documentation.

Comment: I found one term called "sandbox" for an App. Now, Confusion is which Data and/or App can be considered to be accessed.

Comment: An app can only access its own data.